# Google Charts & jQuery Mobile not showing up

Tags: jquery, mobile, charts

I have a jquery mobile site that pulls some information from a postgre sql server using php. When I click on my link to the page, the AJAX loading icon appears, but when the page loads where is nothing on it, just blank white space. When I check the source for the page I see that everything is showing up normally. So after clicking refresh the page shows up exactly as it should appear. Here is the code, I am thinking that the google chart onload function isn't working correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Level Status</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css"      />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<?php 
    include("database_login.php");

    // Connect to Database
    $db_handle = pg_connect("host=$pg_host port=$pg_port dbname=$pg_database user=$pg_user password=$pg_password");

    // Wuery string
    $query = "SELECT Levels.Level, CASE Levels.Closed WHEN true THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'Open' END, SUM(CASE WHEN JobType = 0 AND Finished IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN JobType != 0 AND Finished IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Levels LEFT JOIN Jobs
    ON Levels.Level = Jobs.Level WHERE Levels.Level > 0 GROUP BY Levels.Level, Levels.Closed ORDER BY Levels.Level;";

    $result = pg_exec($db_handle, $query);
?>   
<script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Level');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Output');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Input');
    data.addRows(21);
    <?php        
        $x=0;
        $y=0;
        while($final=pg_fetch_array($result)) 
        {        
            echo "data.setCell($x, $y, $final[0]);\n";
            $y++;
            echo "data.setCell($x, $y, '$final[1]');\n";
            $y++;
            echo "data.setCell($x, $y, $final[2]);\n";
            $y++;
            echo "data.setCell($x, $y, $final[3]);\n";
            $x++;
            $y=0;
     }
    ?>
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(data, {allowHtml: true});
  }
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
    <h1>System Level Status</h1>
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Home</a>
</div>

<!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <div class="content-primary">
    <h2>Current Status of All Levels</h2>   
    <div id='table_div'></div>
    </div>  

    <!--/content-primary -->        

    <div class="content-secondary">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
                <h3>More in this section</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview"  data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Toolkit</li>
                    <li><a href="lookup_jobs.html">Lookup Jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="lookup_palletid.html">Lookup Pallet ID's</a></li>
                   <li><a href="bot_alerts.php">Bot Alerts</a></li>
                   <li data-theme="a"><a href="levelstatus.html">Level Status</a></li>
                   <li><a href="index.html">CMS Logs</a></li>   
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>

<!-- /secondary content -->

<div data-role="footer" class="footer-docs" data-theme="c">
        <p>&copy; 2011-2012</p>
</div>
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found a work around for now, I added data-ajax="false" to the end of the link on the home page to disable ajax and now everything shows up fine. Would still be nice to figure out why this doesn't work though. I'll keep fiddling with it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI,
You are correct in that the google.setOnLoadCallback is what doesn't work. No worries, it is a simple fix. Just use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    drawTable();
});
```